# Taking CouchDB for a test drive on OS X

Tags: macos, couchdb

I'd like to take CouchDB for a spin on OS X (El Capitan).

The installation (via MacPorts) helpfully says:

```
Run the following command to load the CouchDB launchd plist in order to start the service now and at system startup:

sudo port load couchdb
```

but I don't want to run CouchDB at every boot. I just want to run a session one time.

MacPorts installed couchdb in `/opt/local/bin/couchdb`. Just running

```
> couchdb
```

at the terminal gives me a mouthful:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/opt/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/opt/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{error,eacces}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,56}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{_}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

How do I launch CouchDB once?

I tried the `sudo port uninstall erlang` followed by `sudo port install erlang +ssl` trick, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An evasive solution, but it works.

Do not install CouchDB through MacPorts (writing in August 2017).

Install instead by downloading `Apache-CouchDB-1.6.1.zip` or similar, which expands to `Apache CouchDB.app`. Then you'll be greeted with the friendly welcome at http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/

[image: CouchDB welcome page]